# reversing admin "change" url

Tags: django, django-url-reverse

I´m trying to find some example of how to use change url of modelAdmin and what exactly result it gives. Sincerly I do not understand the part from docs:

> "This will find the first registered instance of the admin application (whatever the instance name), and resolve to the view for changing poll.Choice instances in that instance."

Comment: The "change list", or of a single item (so with an edit form)?

Comment: of a single itme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse with:

```
reverse('app:poll_choice_change', kwargs={'object_id': pk})
```

With *`app`* the default namespace (you can specify a different one if you include this in the `path(…)` where you attach the `admin.urls`. *`poll`* the name of the app, *`choice`* the name of the model in lowercase, and *`pk`* the primary key of the object.